# Paypal SDK Support on iphone Devices

Tags: iphone, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to about paypal SDK support for devices. Does it supports iOS 3.0 and onwards? I have tried the demo app available with sdk but it runs on 4.1 simulator. But when i installed it on device its running on iOS 3.1 also.

So, I want to know whether it support the more lower versions of iOS or not?

Your Support is necessory. Please Suggest me something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will run on later iOS versions. You just need to change the `Base SDK` to `Latest`, and `iOS Deployment Target` to whatever you plan to be the lowest version of the iOS you support.